# Extend main APFS partition fails with "target disk is too small for this operation"

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         125.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Storage                 100.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +125.7 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            122.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 19.9 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                506.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

I checked the different similar questions and tried the suggested solutions but in vain. Disk utility doesn't help at all.

I tried running this command from the terminal as suggested.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Error: -69771: The target disk is too small for this operation

I have more than 25 G of free space:

[image: https://imgur.com/8o9RBvo]

Comment: disk0s3 is blocking any expansion of disk0s2 (which would require some free disk space directly "after" disk0s2). Check this with `sudo gpt -r show disk0`.

Comment: @klanomath I'm getting gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': Operation not permitted. I agree that seems to be the problem but I have no clue how to solve it

Comment: @Ahmed: You have boot to macOS Recovery before issuing the `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The free space resides after `disk0s3`. The command you issued can not reclaim the free space back into `disk0s2`, because there little or no free space between `disk0s2` and `disk0s3`. To reclaim approximately 25 GB of free space back to `disk0s2`, you would need to execute the following procedure.

1. Remove the files from `disk0s3`.
2. Delete disk `disk0s3`. You can use the command given below.

   ```
   sudo diskutil  eraseVolume free none disk0s3
   ```
3. Add the approximately 125 GB of free space to `disk0s2`. You can use the command given below.

   ```
    sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
   ```

Basically, it come down to this. If the files on `disk0s3` are important, then you are going to need an external drive to temporarily store them. Once all the space has been returned to `disk0s2`, you can either create a new `disk0s3` or create another APFS volume on `disk0s2`. Finally, restore the files from the external drive.

Comment: Hint: For others wishing to answer this question, post how to use the `dd` command to move `disk0s3` to the end of the drive. You would probably have to move the partition in four 25 GB blocks.