# Can't extend APFS after erasing old partition as free space

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, apfs, diskutil

My problem is very similar to this one:
[Extend main APFS partition fails with "target disk is too small for this operation"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312182/extend-main-apfs-partition-fails-with-target-disk-is-too-small-for-this-operati)

I erased an unused 80 GB partition as free space, and I would like to extend my APFS container to fill up all the free space.

I tried to resize the container but I get the error `The target disk is too small for this operation`

I booted into recovery mode and did a `diskutil list`:

```
[200~-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         168.7 GB   disk1s2
   3:                        EFI U                       500.2 MB   disk1s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +168.7 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            142.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 23.0 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                519.0 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk19

/dev/disk20 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk20
```

It seems like disk3 - disk20 are suspicious, maybe I don't need those?

Is there a way to gain all my free space back on the APFS container?

Answer (score 0):

the solution to my issue was exactly the same as the one in [the similar question I mentioned in my original post here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312182/extend-main-apfs-partition-fails-with-target-disk-is-too-small-for-this-operati#answer-312406)

apparently in my case, the extra EFI partition there was in between the free space and the APFS partition, after I deleted that, I was about to run `diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0` to reclaim the free space