# mac merge 2 apfs containers, free container is not first on disk

Tags: mac, hard-drive, partition, apfs

I got a used macbook pro off of ebay.  The previous owner had a recovery image taking up 420G on a separate containers.  I am trying to merge the containers, but the system does not like it because the boot container is after the free space so it does not want to merge the containers.  This does  not work: [How can I merge primary APFS partition with other empty APFS partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301884/how-can-i-merge-primary-apfs-partition-with-other-empty-apfs-partition).

```
$ sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 0
Password:
Started APFS operation
Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size
```

I think this fails because the free container is first on the disk

Ideas?

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         420.0 GB   disk0s4
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         80.1 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +80.1 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Boot                    52.5 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 42.2 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +69.2 MB    disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Paragon Hard Disk Ma... 69.2 MB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +420.0 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume test                    639.0 KB   disk3s1
```

Comment: If it's new to you & still has any old data on it, first task should be to use Internet Recovery & completely wipe the drive, then install a brand new, clean OS, which will then belong to you - otherwise it still belongs to the old owner.

Comment: **This is a solution in this case:** https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312182/extend-main-apfs-partition-fails-with-target-disk-is-too-small-for-this-operati

Comment: It was wiped with a new OS loaded, but it was done incorrectly and I am hoping to not have to reload the OS and set everything up again.  That would be the final solution, but I did not want to jump to that yet.

Comment: @GregColeson You don't know whether the old owner has installed malware/spyware on the device. Wipe and reinstall macOS.