# How to merge "unmerge-able APFS drive" into one partition?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I have a little problem. My MacBook has two spare partitions - 29GB and 6GB. Both are in the APFS format and I cannot remove them with Disk Utility. The 29GB was created from shrinking the Bootcamp volume. The 6GB.. I don't know.

All drives' list from iTerm:

```
karelus@MacBook-Pro-Karol ~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         394.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                70.3 GB    disk0s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         29.4 GB    disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         6.3 GB     disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +6.3 GB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s5
   1:                APFS Volume Built-In SecureConta... 1.6 MB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +29.4 GB    disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s4
   1:                APFS Volume APFS                    1.3 MB     disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +394.0 GB   disk3
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Preboot                 2.1 GB     disk3s2
   2:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk3s3
   3:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk3s4
   4:                APFS Volume APPLE SSD – dane        270.1 GB   disk3s5
   5:                APFS Volume macOS                   8.6 GB     disk3s7
   6:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 8.6 GB     disk3s7s1
```

[image]
[image]

So how can I merge these partitions into macOS partition (into disk0 or disk0s2 partition)?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/IohnTIk) < Pictures from Disk Utility

Comment: You can't, they're not touching each other—the boot camp partition is blocking them.

Comment: so how can I make them "touching each other"?

Comment: delete or move the boot camp partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the unwanted APFS partitions and move the Windows Boot Camp partition to the end of the disk. Once this is accomplished, you can use the macOS command below to reclaim the free space.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

See the question below for discussion of third party tools that can remove APFS partitions and move Windows partitions.

- [Missing around 20 GB of Space on MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432199/missing-around-20-gb-of-space-on-macbook)
- [How to add to macOS (free space) from diskutil list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434419/how-to-add-to-macos-free-space-from-diskutil-list)