# Can not claim free space after bootcamp partition, I do not want to remove my bootcamp

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I have removed a Container I used to have after bootcamp partition, so now I have 246.1 GB free space as can be seen in the diskutil list below:

```
MacBook-Pro ~ % diskutil list                          
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         625.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                128.8 GB   disk0s4
                    (free space)                         246.1 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +625.3 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.7 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 11.7 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     248.3 GB   disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume Preboot                 3.7 GB     disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s5
```

I have tried using `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`, to add it to my Macintosh HD, but I have got the following, and of course I assume is because of Bootcamp partition.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
Started APFS operation
Error: -69519: The target disk is too small for this operation, or a gap is required in your partition map which is missing or too small, which is often caused by an attempt to grow a partition beyond the beginning of another partition or beyond the end of partition map usable space
```

The thing is, I do not want to remove my bootcamp as I have multiple configurations there.

Is there a way to add that free space to my `Macintosh disk0s2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has be asked before. For example, see [Missing around 20 GB of Space on MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432199/missing-around-20-gb-of-space-on-macbook).

Another similar question would be [How to add to macOS (free space) from diskutil list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434419/how-to-add-to-macos-free-space-from-diskutil-list). Here the basic difference is you do not have a partition named `OSXRESERVED`. You just need to move the partition named `BOOTCAMP` to the end of the drive.

Included with these questions are explanations of how the ***free*** software GParted or MiniTool Partition Wizard can be used to move Windows partitions on Intel Macs.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the link, I missed that article, I finally achieved using mini partition tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly expand a volume or partition with another in the way, as you surmised. You need to move the other partition up to the end of the drive first.

This *might* be possible from the command line, but it's not something I have any experience with.
If you want to be able to do this from a GUI interface, the only app I know that can move & resize partitions, including Boot Camp, is [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/).

This is not something I'd attempt without a known-good backup.

Comment: I noticed  Paragon Hard Disk Manager support for Monterey is beta and Ventura support is not shown. Another possible *"for pay"* software, which runs from macOS, would be [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/).

Comment: They've always been a bit slow to fully support each OS. I haven't had cause to use it on Monterey & I don't see me adopting Ventura in the building any time soon. My upgrade policy with Apple has gone from 'first-day adventurer' 20 years ago to 'always stay one entire OS behind, let others do the beta testing.'